# How does cycle index change along an equivariant map?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, group-actions

**Question.** Suppose $G$ acts on $X$ (via $\Psi$) and on $Y$ (via $\Phi$), and let $f : X\to Y$ be an equivariant map ($f(g\cdot x) = g\cdot f(x)$ for all $x$ in $X$ and $g$ in $G$). Is there a formula relating the cycle indices $Z_\Psi$ and $Z_\Phi$? For example, is there some substitution which transforms one of these polynomials into the other?

**Background.** Though the cycle index (polynomial) is usually defined for permutation groups, there is no loss to extend it to *group actions*: if $G \curvearrowright X$ then there is a group homomorphism $\Psi : G \to \mathfrak{S}_X$ and each $\Psi(g)$ partitions $X$ into cycles. The cycle type $c(g)$ of $\Psi(g)$ is then an $n$-tuple (here, $n = |X|$) of non-negative integers $c_l$ which count the number of cycles of length $l$ that $\Psi(g)$ has (as a permutation of $X$). 
We encode all this data in the cycle index: $$Z_\Psi(z_1, \dotsc, z_n) = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} z^{c(g)}$$
where we use the shorthand $z^{(c_1, ..., c_l)} = z_1^{c_1} ... z_n^{c_n}$. 
Note that we do not have to assume that the action is faithful; if $H = \ker\Psi$ and $\overline{\Psi}:G/H\to \mathfrak{S}_X$ be the induced action, then $Z_{\overline{\Psi}} = Z_\Psi$ because $c(\bar{g}) = c(g)$ and $|G/H| = |G|/|H|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably no answer. Working with a few examples led me to realize that the cycle index polynomial is already "reduced" in the sense that it's not the most general invariant associated with an action.

When computing $Z_{G \curvearrowright X}$, the standard simplifying observation is to notice that, since the monomial $z^{c(g)}$ depends only on the cycle type of the permutation of $X$ induced by $g$, it suffices to sum over all possible cycle types, or, what is equivalent, over all possible partitions of $X$.

The "right" way to compute $Z_{G \curvearrowright X}$ is to sum over all conjugacy classes of $G$. Conjugate elements always have the same cycle type because their induced permutations of $X$ are conjugate, and so they have identical dynamics. But the partition of $G$ arising from the equivalence relation "$\Psi(g)$ and $\Psi(g')$ have the same cycle type" is usually coarser than the conjugacy relation, and there are situations where a cycle type class will split along an equivariant map! I did not expect this—I tacitly assumed that cycle type would be preserved—which is why I believed a formula relating $Z_{G \curvearrowright X}$ and $Z_{G \curvearrowright Y}$ might exist.

Here is an example. Let $n \ge 4$ be even, $G = D_n = \langle r, s \mid r^n, s^2, (sr)^2\rangle$, and $X = C_n = \langle c \mid c^n\rangle$. Let $G$ act on $X$ by $r\cdot x = cx$ and $s\cdot x = x^{-1}$.  This is the standard faithful action of $D_n$ on an $n$-gon; I incorporated the group structure of $C_n$ to simplify my calculations.

The conjugacy classes of $D_n$ are $\{1\}$, $\{r^k, r^{-k}\}$ for $1 \le k < n/2$, $\{r^{n/2}\}$, $s\langle r\rangle$, and $sr\langle r\rangle$. In the above action of $D_n$ on $C_n$, the group elements $r^{n/2}$ and $sr$ have the same cycle type (namely, $z_2^{n/2}$) so their cycle type class comprises the two conjugacy classes $\{r^{n/2}\}$ and $\{sr, sr^3, sr^5, \dotsc\}$.

Now let $d$ be a positive divisor of $n$ and consider the subgroup $H = \langle c^d \rangle$ of $C_n$. If we are thinking of the elements of $C_n$ as vertices of an $n$-gon, then $H$ is every $d$th vertex starting from $1$. Let $Y = C_n/\langle c^d\rangle$. The obvious action of $D_n$ on $Y$ (i.e. $g\cdot(xH) = (g\cdot x)H$) actually works, and the natural map $X \to Y$ sending $x$ to $xH$ is equivariant!

Under this new action, the elements $r^{n/2}$ and $sr$ behave differently. The cycle type of $r^{n/2}$ is $z_1^d$ or $z_2^{d/2}$ according as $n/d$ is even or odd. The cycle type of $sr$ is $z_2^{d/2}$ or $z_1z_2^{(d-1)/2}$ according as $d$ is even or odd (the sole fixed point being $c^{(d-1)/2}\langle c^d\rangle$ in the latter case). So, for example, with $n=4$ and $d=2$, thinking of a square and its two diagonals, the $z_2^2$-class $\{r^2, sr, sr^3\}$ splits, with $r^2$ joining $1$, $s$, and $sr^2$ in the $z_1^2$-class while $sr$ and $sr^3$ join $r$ and $r^3$ in the $z_2$-class!